# How to enable debugging for CLion

Tags: c++, clion

I'm using out of the box CLion installation on my Apple MacBook, creating new C++ project, selecting proper build configuration, putting breakpoint on first line of hello world application (in other words doing everything necessary to start a debug build) BUT after pressing debug button nothing happens.

Messages Build shows the following list of messages:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/Lu4/Projects/!/CppDebug1/cmake-build-debug --target CppDebug1 -- -j 4
[100%] Built target CppDebug1
```

And thats it, I've tried everything, changing CMake version, changing debugger version, changing C++ version from 14 to 11:

[image: Preferences]

It looks like debug build is not starting an application at all...

Any advice on this matter? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you set in configuration binary to be debug?

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` contains `SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-D_DEBUG")` if I understood you correctly. It looks as the executable doesn't start at all, no program messages are displayed.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1seY24d.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FVOGJEj.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jA8pkhe.png

Comment: Is the build working? I can se you have that configured in your screen.

Comment: Yes, the build is working, the application runs when you pick just Run but it doesn't when you pick Debug

Answer (score 0):

After running this script, and restarting CLion, I've managed to start debugging:

https://gist.github.com/denji/9731967

Hope it helps if someone will ever face the same problem...